# I have a txt file and want to print specific words

Tags: python

This is my text file:

```
10.10.10.10 POST /include/jquery.js HTTP/1.1 233 
192.10.10.12 POST /include/jquery.js HTTP/1.1 232 
10.10.10.12 POST /node/jquery.jshowoff2.js HTTP/1.1 23e
171.1.1.15 POST /include/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1 121
10.10.10.10 POST /text/jquery.sho.min.js HTTP/1.1 233
```

I want to print the file name only with the `.js` included.
For example, for the first line I want to get printed out:
**jquery.js**

This is what I have now, but it is printing the complete lines

```
import re
import sys
linenum = 0
substr = '.js'
with open ('access_log.txt', 'rt') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        linenum += 1
        if line.find(substr) != -1: 
            print(line, end=' ')
```

Output:

```
10.10.10.10 POST /include/jquery.js HTTP/1.1 233 
 192.10.10.12 POST /include/jquery.js HTTP/1.1 232 
 10.10.10.12 POST /node/jquery.jshowoff2.js HTTP/1.1 23e
 171.1.1.15 POST /include/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1 121
 10.10.10.10 POST /text/jquery.sho.min.js HTTP/1.1 233
```

Comment: Please provide complete code. What is `substr`?

Comment: Fix your indentations and provide a working [mre]

Comment: `line.split()[2].split('/')[-1]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unique_files = set()

    with open('data/text-file-specific-words.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            for word in line.split():
                tokens = word.split('/')
                for token in tokens:
                    if token.endswith('.js'):
                        unique_files.add(token)

    print(sorted(unique_files))
```

Comment: thank you, is there a way to sort the results and remove the ones that are duplicates?

Comment: @titoluna07 I edited my answer for sorting and remove duplicates. Consider upvoting and accepting the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use the `rfind()` method to find the index of the last occurring `'/'` in a string, if there is one:

```
import re

with open('access_log.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        st = line.split()
        print([a[a.rfind('/')+1:] for a in st if a.endswith('.js')])
```

Output:

```
['jquery.js']
['jquery.js']
['jquery.jshowoff2.js']
['jquery.min.js']
['jquery.sho.min.js']
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the input. It prints all the lines with the "[]" even if they don't have the.js at the end, but it only shows the lines that have .js. thanks!